# Power query advanced editor. Filter column on current year

Tags: powerquery, powerbi-desktop, m

I have a column named Exercise and in this column there is year. IE: 2021

How could i say to my filter to filter on current year only? I do not want to input a fixed year...

Answer (score 0):

Use may as a variable:

```
CurrentYear = Date.Year(DateTime.LocalNow())
```